# UISplitViewController inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have the following scenario and and I don't know if the workflow is right. With the iPad App the user should use the following Workflow

TabBar -> CollectionView -> SplitView

If I use an NavigationController before the CollectionView, it works fine, but if I navigation from CollectionView to SplitView it doesn't work. I get the error

> Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller

If I don't use the NavigationController in front of the CollectionView, my SplitView would displayed on Modal. I don't know if it is possible to display SplitView inside NavigationView

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put a UISplitViewController into a UINavigationController. Apple docs say, that a UISplitViewController always has to be the RootViewController of the applications UIWindow, but even Apple breaks this rule. Better think of redesigning your UI.